# Exclude match in Regular Expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Is it possible to ignore a specific match in a regular expression?

**For example:**

I have the following regular expression:

```
^[0-9]{2}$
```

But I don't want to match a specific string, let's say "12".

I think I'm looking for something like an *and* operator for regular expressions, but haven't been able to find anything like this in .NET / C#.

I would prefer to do this in the regular expression itself.
Any advice or suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^[0-9]{2}(?<!12)$
```

Or the reverse:

```
^(?!12)[0-9]{2}$
```

Note that in this *specific* case, negating 1 specific match was easy. Sometimes it isn't, an sometimes it's (nigh) impossible, depends on the regex.

Comment: Excellent! How is this called? I would like to read more about it... :)

Comment: [Negative lookbehind & lookaheads @ regularexpressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Thank you! This can be quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off doing something like:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(MyString, @"^[0-9]{2}$") && MyString != "12")
{
    // Do something
}
```

Regex are very powerful, but it's important to know when to NOT use them :)

Comment: @JOE: I agree but in this case Wrikken answer is straightforward, taken into account you know lookarounds

Comment: In this case it wouldn't be so easy, because Regexps are stored in a DB and are evaluated dynamically...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this ugly regexp:

```
^([02-9][0-9] | [1][013-9])$
```

Translated to plain English, it means "a two-digit string that does not start in `1`, or a two-digit string that starts in `1` but does not have `2` as its second digit".